# Unit Test ViewModels Inheriting from Screen (Caliburn.Micro)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, tdd, caliburn.micro

I've started learning TDD, and I bumped into ViewModel testing. I'm using Caliburn.Micro as my MVVM framework, and my ViewModels are inheriting from Screen.

When I create try to test a ViewModel, I get this error:

> The type 'Caliburn.Micro.Screen' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Caliburn.Micro'

Is this OK? I think isolating my classes from the framework is the right path, but I don't know how should I do it (preserving the benefits the framework gives by inheriting from Screen)

Thanks,
Martín

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is okay to add the reference. The only alternative is dynamically creating the type, which does not really offer you much advantage.

I assume your ViewModel will not try to display any screens. If it does you will need to subclass it to get a version that can be unit tested.

I haven't used Caliburn.Micro but it sounds a bit odd that your ViewModel inherits from Screen. Normally with MVVM the ViewModel knows about the View but does not inherit from one. A quick Google search suggests that in Caliburn.Micro the ViewModel implements the IScreen interface, as opposed to inheriting from Screen.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I've been reading Caliburn.Micro's documentation, and I think inheriting from Screen is really common (see [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation)).

Comment: @Michael, the Caliburn Screen just means that this ViewModel is a chunky/aggregate VM - the equivalent of a WebPage. It is just an interface with some additional requirements like CanClose() AFAIR.

Answer (score 0):

Does the dependency on Screen pull in a bunch of other things too... if not, might not be a big deal.

The ViewModels are part of the presentation layer and are usually coupled with the GUI framework that you use.. Corollary: the ViewModels might need to be reworked/thrown away when the GUI framework changes unless you design for it (separate the business logic from the presentation and push it down). If you're incensed by this para, check out [Robert Martin's talk on Clean architecture](http://vimeo.com/43612849) at NDC Oslo (available online)

Comment: Hi Gishu. I can't find that talk online. Would you give me a link? Thanks. As regards testing the ViewModel, would you say it's okay to reference Caliburn.Micro dll from Tests project? I'm currently separating my business logic in another layer, but I'd also want to have the ViewModels decoupled as much as posible.